# showing video and photo in gridview also duration of video

Tags: android, gridview, storage

[**click this image to see what I have done **
I have done showing images but also video but I can't find differentiate between them the look same ..!! also I need to show them duration of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMld6.png)

*** this is my gallery activity***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);
    //setupBottomNavigationView();
    directories = new ArrayList<>();
    directorySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerDirectory);
    mProgressbar = (LottieAnimationView)findViewById(R.id.mprogressbar);
    galleryImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.shareGridView);

    back = (LottieAnimationView)findViewById(R.id.share_activity_back);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back ");
            finish();
        }
    });

    takephoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Camera_take_photo);
    takephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkPermissions(Permissions.CAMERA_PERMISSION[0])){
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting camera");
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

            }else {


            }
        }
    });

    if (checkPermissionsArray(Permissions.PERMISSIONS)){

    }else{
        verifyPermissions(Permissions.PERMISSIONS);

    }
    init();

}
public void verifyPermissions(String[] permissions){
    Log.d(TAG, "verifyPermissions: verifying permissions.");

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            ShareActivity.this,
            permissions,
            VERIFY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST
    );
}

/**
 * Check an array of permissions
 * @param permissions
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPermissionsArray(String[] permissions){
    Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissionsArray: checking permissions array.");

    for(int i = 0; i< permissions.length; i++){
        String check = permissions[i];
        if(!checkPermissions(check)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Check a single permission is it has been verified
 * @param permission
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPermissions(String permission){
    Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissions: checking permission: " + permission);

    int permissionRequest = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ShareActivity.this, permission);

    if(permissionRequest != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissions: \n Permission was not granted for: " + permission);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, " Please allow the permission \n for reading your external storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissions: \n Permission was granted for: " + permission);
        return true;
    }

}
private  void setupBottomNavigationView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up bottam navigation view");
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx)findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_viewbar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNAvigation(mContext,bottomNavigationViewEx);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
private void init(){
    FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();
    if (FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES) != null){
        directories = FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES);
    }
    directories.add(filePaths.CAMERA);
    directories.add(filePaths.VEDIO);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,directories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    directorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    directorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            setupGridView(directories.get(position));
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
private void setupGridView(String selectedDirectory){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: directory chosen: " + selectedDirectory);
    final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);
    //set the grid column width
    int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
    gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);
    //use the grid adapter to adapter the images to gridview
    GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(mContext, R.layout.layout_gridview, mAppend, imgURLs);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: done taking photo");
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: attempting to take it to final share screen ");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "One more step to publish this photo ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

this is my File_search class and File_Path class

1 *** File_Search class**

```
public class FileSearch {
/**
 * Search a directory and return a list of all **directories** contained inside
 * @param directory
 * @return
 */
public static ArrayList<String> getDirectoryPaths(String directory){
    ArrayList<String> pathArray = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(directory);
    File[] listfiles = file.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++){
        if(listfiles[i].isDirectory()){
            pathArray.add(listfiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return pathArray;
}
/**
 * Search a directory and return a list of all **files** contained inside
 * @param directory
 * @return
 */
public static ArrayList<String> getFilePaths(String directory){
    ArrayList<String> pathArray = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(directory);
    File[] listfiles = file.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++){
        if(listfiles[i].isFile()){
            pathArray.add(listfiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return pathArray;
}
```

}

2 **File_Path class**

```
    //"storage/emulated/0"
    public String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    public String PICTURES = ROOT_DIR + "/Pictures";
    public String CAMERA = ROOT_DIR + "/DCIM/camera";
    //public String VEDIO = ROOT_DIR + "/videos";
    public String FIREBASE_STORY_STORAGE = "stories/users";
    public String FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE = "photos/users/";

}
```

please help struggleing this from past 6 hours

Comment: Do you know the type of each file?

Comment: what are you talking about??? yes I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the type of the returned files such as jpg, png, mp4 etc. then you can differentiate it in your custom GridImageAdapter. In your image item xml file, you can create another `ImageView` holding a play icon in center of your every item. This icon will be hidden in case of image file, however, if there is a video file then you can show this icon in your custom adapter.

Also, you want to get the duration of video, for that you can use `MediaMetadataRetriever` as follows:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
//use one of overloaded setDataSource() functions to set your data source
retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time );

retriever.release()
```

Comment: I want to get duration of the video

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever can be used to get video duration of video. please check updated answer

Comment: Fahed Yasin Thanks!!

Comment: if you can please accept my answer, that will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Fahed how can I get all video from phone storage to grid view